# SPFx List View Formatter extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, spfx, json-formatting, spfx-extensions

Is there any way to format the ListView by using the SPFx extension same as we have format the ListView as JSON formatting?

I can format the ListView using the JSON format, but for that, I need to assign the JSON formatting to the lists. And whenever I will create a new list, then I have to assign the JSON formatting. But I want that will automatically apply the formatting on all the lists.

**Note**: My requirement is to apply the same formatting on all the lists to the existing and/or a new list on the SharePoint site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using SPFx extensions.

However, you can apply view formatting to lists programmatically using [Set-PnPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpview) command in PnP PowerShell.

**Example**:

```
Set-PnPView -List "MyList" -Identity "MyViewName" -Values @{CustomFormatter = @'my-json-formatted-string'@}
```

**Reference**: [Updating a view format using PnP PowerShell](https://beaucameron.com/2020/06/01/json-column-formatting-name-cannot-begin-with-the-character/)

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Is there any other way that I will apply the formatting automatically?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any other way to apply view formatting to all existing & new lists. This is the quickest & easiest way. You just need to loop through all the lists on site & apply view formatting using above command.